# 200 unique respondents, over 3000 observations?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models

If doing a survey study with 200 respondent resulting in over 3000 observations (respondents answer several questions) how do you approach this with a regression? We've split the data into segments with the same questions in each segment and unique respondents and are wondering if comparing these segments to each other would be good, and if so, how to proceed?

The outcome is customer perception of price and quality (continuous) on several different product designs on the predictors (color, morphology, design type etc.). The objective is to see if there is a statistically significant difference in perception of price between designs. Each product has been shown to the users with different designs and each has been listed in color, design type, morphology etc. which is then shown in various different ways to different users. When looking at whether color is different, we obviously want to control for the other aspects of the design to see if it truly is color that was perceived as more expansive.

We thought of using `xtset (segmentVariable)` and `xtgee dependent independent`

But an error occurs as we are trying to create too many matrices for our Stata edition... Surely we are not at a place where we need to upgrade to a premium edition as students?

Comment: What are the objectives of your study?  They are the primary determinants of what you must do.

Comment: Added, can you reopen the question if it suffices?

Comment: You haven't stated any objectives.  Further, your edits suggest additional complications: it looks like you wish to study a large number of outcomes rather than a single one--but what you really are trying to do is still unknown to the rest of us.

Comment: I have tried to elaborate further.

Comment: Paze, the research question (e.g., does change in $x$ predict change in $y$?) drives the choice in methods (e.g., regression), not the other way around. Your question would get *much* more traction if you stated your research question.

Comment: "The objective is to see if there is a statistically significant difference in perception of price between designs."

I'm not sure how I can explain this further?